# Compound conditionals in Bash Shell to check multiple conditions in one if check

Tags: bash, shell

What is wrong with following if conditions. I am trying to check if two arguments are being passed and if the first argument contains only string elements with alphabets and second argument contains only string with numbers.

```
if [[ ( "$#" == 2 ) && ( "$1" =~ ^[A-Za-z]*$) && ( "$2" =~ [0-9] ) ]]
```

It throws up following error

```
cw_validation.sh: line 2: syntax error in conditional expression
'w_validation.sh: line 2: syntax error near `]]
'w_validation.sh: line 2: `if [[ ( "$#" == 2 ) && ( "$1" =~ ^[A-Za-z]*$) && ( "$2" =~ [0-9] ) ]]
```

Edit:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "$#" == 2 && "$1" =~ ^[A-Za-z]*$ && "$2" =~ [0-9] ]]
    then
        secretKey=admin123
        retries=4
        echo "Please enter the secret key to run the program"
        read inputKey
        while [[ ( "$inputKey" != "$secretKey" ) && ( "$retries" -ge 0) ]]
        do
            echo "Please enter the correct secret key to run the program. Retries left: $retries"
            
else
    echo Wrong Format
    echo "Correct Format: bash cw_edit student's_first_name id"
    echo "e.g bash Samit 19032423"
fi
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Can you post a longer snippet of code. Ideally a complete minimal example we can copy, paste and run to reproduce your error?

Comment: maybe you are using `sh` instead of `bash`?

Comment: Stupid question, but it comes up more often that you'd think: does your script start with `#!/bin/bash`? If not, fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Your script file formatted with DOS `\r\n` line endings. You can tell by the position of the closing single quote in the error message (positioned at the start of the line)

```
cw_validation.sh: line 2: syntax error in conditional expression
'w_validation.sh: line 2: syntax error near `]]
^
```

Alter the line endings with `dos2unix` or `sed -i 's/\r$//' cw_validation.sh`, and update the settings on your editor to save with "UNIX" line endings.